# Play lyrics automatically with mpv

Tags: configuration, mpv

Mpv is not loading and playing lyrics files, even though they're in the same directory with the same name but different `.lrc` file extension.
and I even have the following in my mpv.conf file

```
autoload-files=yes
sub-auto=fuzzy
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1398561/788170 I use SRT subs for each song.

Answer (score 3):

it seems that even with these options, mpv doesn't load LyRiCs (`.lrc`) files.
what I had to do is make a little mpv plugin script, and put it in the `scripts` directory which's in the `config` directory of mpv.

```lua
--  load lrc files

function file_exists(name)
   local f=io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
end

function GetLrcPath(name)
  return name:gsub("(%..+)$", ".lrc")
end

function open_handler()
        lrcPath = GetLrcPath(mp.get_property("path"))
        if file_exists(lrcPath) then
            mp.set_property("options/sub-files", lrcPath)
        end
end
mp.register_event("start-file", open_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

## In mpv 0.35.0 this works out of the box

- When playing `file.mp3` then without any further configuration the sidecar file `file.lyr` is considered as its subtitle file and is played in sync!
- If you add `sub-auto=fuzzy` to `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` then also `file.en.lyr` and `file.fr.lyr` will get considered as subtitle tracks for `file.mp3` and during playback you can cycle through them with the "Switch Subtitle" button.
- The setting `autoload-files=yes` was not needed at all.